# Concat values from array of strings to another static string in c

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am working on console application in c in VS 2010

```
char rsp[25][9]; //rsp is properly populated by another function suppose it contain three values hello,Goodbye,See you

char txt[] = "Message: ";
int i=0;
while(i<25)
{
    strcat(txt,rsp[i]);
    i++;
}
```

I want to concat txt[ ] with each string of rsp[ ][ ], but it get crash on strcat(txt,rsp[i]), kindly point out the mistake

Comment: with `strcat` in a loop.

Comment: And don't forget to allocate sufficient space to hold the concatenation of two strings, plus the null terminator.

Comment: @adam can you write the code, i am new to c

Comment: In response to your edited question, "kindly point out the mistake", you didn't take note of "And don't forget to allocate sufficient space to hold the concatenation of two strings..."  C doesn't magically grow your strings for you like scripting languages.  You are writing beyond the buffer, causing corruption.

Comment: The buffer size of `txt[]` is 10 char wide: "Message: \0".  As soon as you concatenate "hello", you have added 5 characters past the end of the buffer: "Message: hello\0" (that's 15 chars).  So "ello\0" extends past the end of `txt[]`, overwriting memory that doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) example will help here. In your code, instead of declaring txt as string "Message: ", you will need to declare `txt` with size 25 * 9 + strlen(""Message: "") to hold all the string :

```
    char bal[] = "Message: ";
    char rsp[25][9]; //rsp is properly populated by another function 
    char *txt;

    txt = (char*) malloc (25*9+strlen(bal)+1); 
    strcpy (txt, bal);  // first copy "Message" to txt
    while(i<25)
   {
    strcat(txt, rsp[i]);
    i++;
   }
```

learn about [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) here. Don't forget to free `txt` at the end of the function.

Comment: In your code, instead of declaring `txt` as string `""Message: ""`, you will need to declare `txt` with size 25*9*strlen(`""Message: ""`) to hold all the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `txt[]="Message: "` has been allocated a fixed space (10bytes) so you cannot concatenate any more strings. I suggest use save "Message: " in a temporary space and use dynamic allocation to reserve appropriate space for entire message

```
int main()
{
int i=0;
char temp[]="Message: ";
char rsp[25][9];
char *text=malloc(25*9+strlen(temp)+1);
strcpy(txt,temp);
for(;i<25;i++)
    strcat(txt,rsp[i]);
}
```